# Where should I put AngularJS scope $watchers?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to get changes to an AngularJS scope to trigger actions in a model. To do this I use `$scope.$watch()` in my item controller, and plug those controllers into directives. The problem I'm having is that when an item appears more than once on a page I'm getting multiple watchers for the same piece of data.

For example:

```
angular.module("MyApp", [])
.factory('ItemsModel', function() {
    var item1 = { triggers: 0, catches: 0 };
    var item2 = { triggers: 0, catches: 0 };

    return {
        getItems: function() { 
            return [item1, item2, item1];
        }
    };
})
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, ItemsModel) {
    $scope.items = ItemsModel.getItems();    
})
.controller('ItemCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.trigger = function() {
        $scope.item.triggers++;
    };    
    $scope.$watch('item.triggers', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if(newValue != oldValue)
            $scope.item.catches++;
    });
})
.directive('item', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            item: "="
        },
        controller: 'ItemCtrl'
    };
});
```

Here `item1` appears twice in the `items` array, so I end up with two controllers watching the same piece of data. If `triggers` were changes to a property, and `catches` were saves back to a server, then I'd be saving each change to item1 twice. If an item appeared three times, it would save three times.

I feel like the change listener should go in the model, but models don't have any access to the scope. Iterating over each item and adding behavior in the AppCtrl doesn't make a lot of sense to me. So where to the watchers go?

I've also put this in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicholasstephan/p56MT/3/

Thanks

Comment: The directive should be used for reusable components. Its not a wrapper for a controller.. And the controller argument for a directive and the ng-controller are two different things. They are not one and the same.

Comment: @ganarj Ok. If I take out the empty directive, and just use ng-controller, the controller is still be called twice for the same piece of data. http://jsfiddle.net/vFtbL/1/ The question is, where should that `$scope.$watch('item.triggers'...` go?

Comment: Could you explain, the real world scenario you are trying to solve ? This is too abstract.

Comment: Anything really. For example, this post is an object with properties: subject, body, comments, tags, etc. I'd like to watch the tags array for changes and trigger a save to the server when a tag is added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the controller specified in the directive like you have here, but an alternative way is to just setup a watch in the directive on item. This way the watch will only get tripped once for the change on item in the directive.